# Google Calender Api integration to web app using api calls

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

Me and my team have built a document management system on top of **App Engine** using java .
We are trying to integrate Google calender to this app . We are new to web services so is there a way to do all operation on Google calender with simple API calls ? If yes, can some one direct me to some helpful links or sample code to do so .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello you'll find everything you need about Google Calendar API on that page :

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

There is a client API library for java, python... I've already used the java one and it's clearly explained how to use it in the documentation.

However, the service asks you to be authenticated to use it. So I suggest you to have a look on OAuth2.0.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

Here are some samples of using google-api-java-client for exemple :
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2